# Sort all rows by length of string in variable X (longer strings first)

Tags: sas

I have a variable UserName that contains IDs of variable length. A shortened example:

[image]

How can I sort all rows by variable X where longer strings are listed first.

Context: This is for calculating HEI 2015 scores using the ASA24 macro. It writes:

```
/*Note: Some users have found that the SAS program will drop observations from the analysis if the ID field is not the same length for all observations.  To prevent this error, the observations with the longest ID length should be listed first when the data is imported into SAS. */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proc `SQL` with an `ORDER BY` clause specifying an ordering value *computed* in a `CASE` expression.

The computation `when length(X) > 8 then -length(X) else 0` ensures longest values are first when sorted and all value lengths <= *some-capping-length* (8) are treated equally

`ORDER BY length(X) desc, X` would also select longest X values first and then by X itself, but length would predominate ordering even when value lengths < 8.

```
data have;
length X $50;
input X; datalines;
GFHsp036
GFHsp038
GFHsp039
GFHsp040
GFHsp0400
GFHsp0401
GFHsp0402
GFHsp04021
;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select * from have
  order by
     case when length(x) > 8 then -length(X) else 0 end,
     X
  ;
quit;

proc print;
  var X / style=[fontfamily='Courier'];
run;
```

[image]

Comment: The `CASE` version is necessary if all values less than *some-length* (8 in sample code) are to be sorted alphabetically regardless of length

Comment: I expected this to work, however I believe SAS is truncating my IDs. After the macro code, I get e.g. ID's like 

47 GFHSp041
48 GFHSp041
49 GFHSp041
...

Is this related to how the macro imports? Code below: 
`
Proc import datafile=Totals
  Out=Totals
  Dbms=csv
  Replace;
  Getnames=yes;
Run;`

Comment: If you have an additional question about macro code, or proc import ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is probably the simplest way to do this

```
data have;
input string $;
datalines;
abcde
ab   
a    
abcd 
abc  
;

proc sql;
   create table want as
   select * from have
   order by length(string) desc;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-ordering IDs did not help in my case as PROC IMPORT needed GUESSINGROWS = MAX.

Please see [SAS Macro Truncating IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509891/sas-macro-truncating-ids)

For how to fix the truncating IDs that this question attempted to fix.